# Cartthrob adds tax to all orders after upgrading to v. 2.5

Tags: cartthrob

After upgrading Carttrob from v 2.4 to 2.5, Cartthrob adds tax to all orders rather than just to the orders in the jurisdictions established in the Tax Settings area.  This happened when upgrading to v 2.4 and it required a support session to fix.  (I don't know what was done to fix it.)

Any help is welcome.